# Read actual numeric value (locale independent) of cell in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way in VBA of reading the locale independent value of a cell e.g. if the regional settings are set to use period as thousands separator and comma for decimal place, I still want a value that displays as "123.456,78" to be returned as 123456.78.
Seems like a very reasonable requirement to read the actual value of a cell rather than the displayed string.
I am trying to avoid replacing periods and commas in a string to achieve this.
I am using Office 365

I've tried setting these:

```
Application.ThousandsSeparator
Application.DecimalSeparator
Application.UseSystemSeparators
```

but they seem to be ignored.

Range.Formula returns what I need for cells that contains a value but not if it contains a formula.

---

@FunThomas This is exactly what I expected so I isolated the problem and tried this.
(1) In Control Panel, change Region to English (Netherlands).
(2) Open new workbook and set Cell Format of A1 to Number, 2 decimal places with 1000 Separator.
(3) Enter "123456,78" into A1. This displays "123.456,78".
(4) Range("A1").Value is 123456,78
(5) Range("A1").Formula is 123456.78

We have spreadhseets that are used in UK and Europe that collect values at the time of saving and write them to a database. I need the numbers to all be collected in UK format. The Range.Formula property gives me what I need but only for entered values, not cells containing formulas.

How can I ensure the value read by VBA is always in a consistent format?

Comment: If the content of the cell is a numeric value, you will get this exact value into VBA. completely independent on any locale settings. You can *display* the value in Excel in various ways (decimal, thousand separator, rounding...), but the *value* doesn't change. But you will have issues if the cell contains a string that only looks like a number.

Comment: If you must do this as part of a VBA routine, and you want to have the numbers output using something different from your system regional settings, you will probably need to format the values as text with your desired format.